# Recursive method not stopping at base case in BST

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I wrote a method that reaches the base case (I can tell because it prints the print statement) but it then loops back and returns null (at the end of the method). Why is my method not stopping at the base case?

Edit: Also, if an object doesn't exist in my BST it doesn't return null. I get a null pointer exception instead which shouldn't happen because of the `if (this.left == null) return null;` or `if (this.right == null) return null;` statements

```
    public MovieInfo findPrefix(String prefix) {
    String key = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1);
    System.out.println("PREFIX: " + prefix + " KEY: " + key + " THIS.KEY: " + this.key);
    System.out.println("PARENT: " + this.data.shortName + " LEFT: " + this.left.data.shortName + " RIGHT: " + this.right.data.shortName);
    System.out.println();
    if (compare(key, this.key)) {
        System.out.println(this.data.ID + " " + this.data.shortName + " " + this.data.fullName + "   " + i);
        return this.data;
    }
    else if (key.compareToIgnoreCase(this.key) < 0) {
        if (this.left == null) return null;
        else this.left.findPrefix(prefix);
    }else if (key.compareToIgnoreCase(this.key) > 0) {
        if (this.right == null) return null;
        else this.right.findPrefix(prefix);
    }
    return null;
}//return the data element MovieInfo where the shortName starts with the prefix
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is stopping at the base case, but previous recursive calls are ignoring what it's returning.

Add `return` in between `else` and your recursive call, e.g.:

```
else return this.left.findPrefix(prefix);
```

As for your NPE, you're accessing members of `left` and `right` in your method before performing the `null` check.  Null-check there also.

Comment: Thank you! I would have been stuck on that forever